# How can I update the parent state by calling a function within a switch in my stateless component ?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My goal is to update the state of my parent component with only a portion of data from the initial Json

So basically if for example the case `text` get triggered:

**1- I return the desired `text` and render it in my component (I succeeded in doing that)**

**2- I also want to take this specific data and store it in the parent state**

**3- I will later use this data to create a form**

I tried many things, I finally managed to update the state of the parent by passing down a **function** to the stateless function `MyFunction`, but I keep getting a **warning** because the `setState` is being called inside the `render`method of the `parent Component`

`Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within`render`or another component's constructor).`

```
const MyFunction = props => {

   switch (props.type) {
       case 'image':
         return  props.json.data[props.key]
         break
       case 'text':
         props.changeParent(props.json.data[props.key])
         return props.json.data[props.key]
         break
       default:
         return "Empty text"
         break
  }
}

class UserComponent extends Component {
 constructor(props){
  super(props)
    this.state = {
     active: false
    }
 }

render(){
  return(
    <div>
      { MyFunction({ type: 'text', key: 'first_name', ...this.props }) }
      <img src={ MyFunction({ type: 'image', key: 'avatar', ...this.props }) } />
    </div>
   )
 }
}

// Parent Component
class App extends Component {
 constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    json:[],
    newJson: []
  }
}

// Fetching data from an api
componentDidMount(){
fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users/2")
   .then(response => response.json())
   .then(json => {
      this.setState({json: json })
 })
}

// Update the parent Json using the data sent from the 2nd child
changeParent(jsonToUpdate){
  this.setState({
    newJson :
       jsonToUpdate
    })
 }

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <UserComponent {...this.state} changeParent={(jsonToUpdate) => this.changeParent(jsonToUpdate)}/>
    </div>
  );
 }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `componentDidMount` lifecycle method and maintain a state for the data returned by `myFunction` to avoid that warning like this

```
class UserComponent extends Component {
 constructor(props){
  super(props)
    this.state = {
     active: false,
     // this state stores the data returned by function
     myFunctionReturnData: ""
    }
 }

componentDidMount(){
  let myFunctionReturnData = MyFunction({ type: 'text', key: 'first_name', ...this.props });
  // Call the function and set the state by returned value
  this.setState({ myFunctionReturnData })
}
render(){
  return(
    <div>
      // Will render returned value when state will be set
      { this.state.myFunctionReturnData }
      <img src={ MyFunction({ type: 'image', key: 'avatar', ...this.props }) } />
    </div>
   )
 }
}
```

**Update::**

If you are calling `MyFunction` multiple times then you should avoid calling `changeParent` inside `MyFunction` because you are calling `MyFunction` inside render and calling `changeParent` inside render will put this in loop because you are updating parent state in `changeParent` function. A better solution i can think of according to given code is this

```
const MyFunction = props => {

   switch (props.type) {
       case 'image':
         return  props.json.data[props.key]
         break
       case 'text':
         // Remove changeParent from here
         return props.json.data[props.key]
         break
       default:
         return "Empty text"
         break
  }
}
```

And in componentDidMount use `MyFunction` to call the `changeParent` like

```
componentDidMount(){
  let myFunctionReturnData = MyFunction({ type: 'text', key: 'first_name', ...this.props });
  // Call the parent function
  this.props.changeParent(myFunctionReturnData)
}
```

You do not need to maintain any state now.

Comment: your solution is giving the same warning and actually `MyFunction({ type: 'text', key: 'first_name', ...this.props })` has to be invoked the return statment of `UserComponent` because I use the returned value there, and I will invoke it many times with different arguments

Comment: It’s not really my goal, imagine I call MyFunction  6 times inside the render method  of ‘myParent’ with different arguments. So basically for every function invocation I want to store those individual values in the state. So for every invocation I will Store ‘type: ‘xxx’, key: ‘xxx’ ‘

Comment: So later I can use this data to create a form for example